# Handling AJAJ return value

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, leaflet

I have been fiddling with Leaflet and different maps lately. I am currently trying to have the markers that are created by onClick events to show the current address that is parsed from a JSON query supplied by an API.

I am successfully parsing the address from the JSON query (console log in onMapClick(e)'s getAddress). What I want to do however is to return this value from the callbacked(?) function and make it visible as the marker's content.

```
function getAddress(lat, lon, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.digitransit.fi/geocoding/v1/reverse?point.lat=' + lat + '&point.lon=' + lon + '&size=1', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (typeof callback == "function") {
        callback.apply(xhr);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

function onMapClick(e) {
  popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("Address is " +
      getAddress(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng, function() {
        var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(resp.features[0].properties.label); //This gives the correct current address in console
        return resp.features[0].properties.label; //This SHOULD return the correct address, verified with the console log, and replace the function call in the marker's content window, however the address appears always as undefined.
      }))
    .openOn(map);
}
```

Comment: When `setContent` is called it appends the return value of `getAddress()` which is undefined, not the return value of the internal callback, as you seem to expect.

Comment: I see! How do I access this internal callbacks return value?

Comment: Postpone popup creation until you have the value received. That is execute your `popup.setLatLng ...` inside the callback.

Comment: I've put a code sample in the answer.

Comment: Thank you Kuba! I marked your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of execution, so that you only use the value when you actually have it returned asynchronously from the API:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
  getAddress(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng, function() {
    var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    popup
      .setLatLng(e.latlng)
      .setContent("Address is " + resp.features[0].properties.label)
      .openOn(map);
  });
}
```